# Can a probability measure on $[0,∞)$ with fixed mean have an arbitrarily high variance?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

For $C>0$ arbitrarily large, is it possible to construct a (Borel) probability distribution $\mu$ such that

1. $\mu$ is supported on $[0,∞),$
2. $\int_0^∞ \; d\mu(x) = 1,$
3. $\int_0^∞ x \; d\mu(x) = 1,\qquad$ and
4. $\int_0^∞ x^2 \; d\mu(x) = C\qquad$?

I suspect it is possible, but my intuition is telling me the opposite—since the worst weighting

Comment: Don't you also need $\int_0^∞ d\mu(x) = 1$ ?

Comment: Naturally, of course! Good spot — edit made

Comment: You are specifying three constraints for a function of a real variable. This should not be a problem. In the range $(-\infty,\infty)$, a Gaussian $\mathcal N(1,C)$ virtually does the trick.

Comment: But of course — my question was about how restrictive this first constraint (1.) is.

The accepted answer clarifies on the "essential reason", but I am curious if you could find an answer with a smooth pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the distribution $\frac{C-1}C\delta_0+\frac1C\delta_C$.